Как получить высоту и ширину png картинки в C#?
Как в C# получить высоту и ширину png картики в C#?

Смотря для какой цели. Если вам после этого нужно её показать в UI, то, вероятно, нужно просто загрузить ей в Bitmap от WPF и WinForms.

using var img = Image.FromFile("..."); далее забирайте нужные значения (Width и Height). Обращу внимание, что в .NET Core и выше, этот компонент был отделен и вынесен в отдельный NuGet пакет (System.Drawing.Common). Ну а так да, как сказали выше, все зависит от целей, вариантов получить эту информацию уйма, хоть сами формат разбирайте.

Надо было сразу писать, что у вас Unity. Ответ я удалил, он конечно же не подходит. И конкретнее написать, зачем вам это. Потому что проверять размеры картинки из файла, это вообще не про игры.

@aepot У меня есть картинная галерея, картины в которой хранятся в папке и есть функция, которая берет файлы по очереди и определяет их ориентацию (если горизонтальная, возвращает false, если вертикальная, то true), сравнив стороны. Потом в зависимости от ориентации скрипт создаёт определенный plane и к нему применяется эта картинка как текстура.                                Мне не хватает только функции, которая будет сравнивать стороны

Ну вы картинки же как-то загружаете, чтобы отобразить, вот там и ищите метаданные.

Я нашёл решение, спасибо
